# Lie 2-Algebra Contractions

Tags: reference-request, lie-algebras, higher-category-theory

Lie algebra contractions play a somewhat interesting role in physics (e.g. giving meaning to the statement "special relativity reduces to Galilean relativity in the $\lim\limits_{c \rightarrow \infty}$" when on the face of it that doesn't make sense -- $c$ is a constant. Contractions essentially formalize how this is to be understood as a statement about the ratio of some characteristic length scales).

Out of curiosity: has any of this been generalized to Lie $2$-algebras (see e.g. [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0307263))? Or even further? Are there any references going in this direction?

Comment: Could you include a reference for what a Lie $n$-algebra is?

Comment: Sure, something along the lines of this (extended to $n>2$, of course, but like I said $n=2$ is good enough for a start): https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0307263

Comment: (In other words, the higher categorical generalization of ordinary Lie groups/algebras)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Contractions (and more generally degenerations) of Lie groups and Lie algebras were generalized to many other algebraic structures, for a little survey see my article [here](https://homepage.univie.ac.at/Dietrich.Burde/papers/burde_31_deg_alg_groups.pdf). There is a strong relationship to deformation theory, and the deformation theory of Lie $n$-algebras has been studied, e.g. see [here](https://www.google.at/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&ved=0ahUKEwjo_pW51ZbRAhXNdFAKHdpjBjsQFgg1MAI&url=https%3A%2F%2Farxiv.org%2Fpdf%2F1005.1028&usg=AFQjCNFPbqTizcDNh9oh39o-PWOLFDaaGQ&sig2=NtRKacQ7ulm7AtKPkkpdJg&bvm=bv.142059868,d.ZWM) for references, section 11.7 and also the paper [Deformations of Lie $2$-algebras](https://arxiv.org/abs/1306.6225) . Certain (jump) deformations correspond to contractions.

Comment: Thanks! I don't know how I didn't find those when searching before... a few quick and likely horribly naive questions before I dive into reading through those references: in the simpler case of an ordinary Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}$, say an "unstable" one, one can deform it to a stable algebra (e.g. Galilean to Poincaré, c.f. $\S$ 2.6 (here)[https://arxiv.org/pdf/hep-th/0410212v1.pdf]). Is there a corresponding notion of stability for general Lie $n$-algebras? And can one think of a Lie algebra as a, e.g., Lie 2-algebra and find deformations from the algebra to other 2-algebras?

Comment: To maybe be a little more clear by using an example: the Galilean algebra is unstable, and so if you care about that sort of thing you deform it to the Poincaré algebra, which is stable. Is there some way to think of the Poincaré algebra as a 2-algebra (I'd imagine there is a forgetful functor from Lie 2-algebras to Lie algebras, just ignoring the 2-morphisms... perhaps reverse that using its adjoint, if it exists?)? In which case, perhaps that 2-algebra is unstable in a suitable sense, and can then be deformed to a stable 2-algebra? (and so on)

Comment: Yes, there is the notion of stability, too, by saying that the "orbit $O(L)$ is open" for $L$, see [here](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/115669/why-no-lie-algebra-degenerate-to-a-rigid-algebra-why-the-closure-of-a-rigid-alg). Note that mathematicians call "stable" algebras *rigid* (see page $5$ of your link, C. Chryssomalakos and E. Okon); Rigid algebras are "on top" of the Hasse diagram of contractions, in an irreducible component of the variety (of Lie algebras or whatever).